# Check for a credit card duplicate with stripe using Node.js

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, node-modules

I am currently implementing stripe into my Node.js api. I've noticed that stripe doesn't throw an error if a credit card is duplicated. I've also noticed that each credit card have a fingerprint attributes which allow me to manually check for duplicate.

But currently I have to add the card to my customer, check for a duplicate and then remove it if it is a duplicate.

I didn't found another way to do it with the node module. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Do you have a specific need for your users to save multiple credit cards in your app? Or do you just want one? If you only ever want to store one credit card, there is a way to specify a card as the default when you persist it. In doing so, it would remove any pre-existing default card. Thus, if you always save the card that way, there can never be any duplicates.

Comment: I do need multiple credit card, but thanks for the workaround.

Answer (score 3):

The fingerprint is available when you retrieve the token server-side.

```
stripe.tokens.retrieve(
  "tok_16eUwpK5S7qVcORZ9ur0xOkl",
  function(err, token) {
    // token.card.fingerprint
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why Stripe doesn't throw an error when saving the same credit card multiple times is that they do so intentionally with good reasons. The rationale behind this is that although a credit card is registered for a single user, it can be used by several people in practice. If you take an example, your family members can use the same card to make purchases.

E.g: Although Amazon doesn't use Stripe, let me clarify the above using Amazon.

- Let's assume that Amazon uses Stripe to store Credit cards.
- You can save the credit card as your card for later purchases.
- Your spouse can also enter the same card and save it for later use.
- This is commonly used, so Stripe thought it was better to allow it.

If you consider the Card object attributes on Stripe (see below), you can see it has two important values

- id
- fingerprint

The id is used to identify a credit card, but the same card added multiple times can have different id values.

The fingerprint is what uniquely identifies a card. You can use this value to check if the same user is trying to add the same card again.

The card object

```
{
   "id":"card_1GkRvi2eZvKYlo2CyZAhyK1J",
   "object":"card",
   "address_city":null,
   "address_country":null,
   "address_line1":null,
   "address_line1_check":null,
   "address_line2":null,
   "address_state":null,
   "address_zip":null,
   "address_zip_check":null,
   "brand":"Visa",
   "country":"US",
   "customer":null,
   "cvc_check":"pass",
   "dynamic_last4":null,
   "exp_month":8,
   "exp_year":2021,
   "fingerprint":"Xt5EWLLDS7FJjR1c",
   "funding":"credit",
   "last4":"4242",
   "metadata":{

   },
   "name":null,
   "tokenization_method":null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Stripe is not giving such facilty on their end. What I suugest , If you want to make less calls to stripe, it is recommended that you store the fingerprints of all the cards locally and use them for checking uniqueness. Storing fingerprints of cards locally is secure and it uniquely identifies a card.